# how to define symbols in c

Tags: c, gcc

I am creating cross platform code(Win and Linux) and in windowsVS the file path is usually used as

```
 "Folder1\\folder2\\file"
```

where as in gcc it should be '/' in the place of '\'

```
 "Folder1/folder2/file"
```

Can anyone suggest a way to use that or is there any #define macro that I can use in assigning this.

Although I have tried using

```
#if __linux__
     #define // '\'
#endif
```

But its throwing an error. Somebody pls help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/` on both platforms. The C APIs for Windows accept both `/` and `\`.